# Automapper Ignoring Member Mapping For Duplicate Field Names (Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping)

Tags: c#, automapper

I am getting the following exception when trying to map two classes.

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 'Error mapping types.'
AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
```

This is a simple reproducible console application demo of the problem:

```
using AutoMapper;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {

                cfg.CreateMap<UserEntity, UserModel>()
                    .ForMember(s => s.Scope, opts => opts.MapFrom(dest => dest.ScopeKey))
                    .ReverseMap();
            });

            IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

            UserModel user = new UserModel() { Name = "john doe", Scope = "private" };
            UserEntity dbUser = mapper.Map<UserEntity>(user);   // <------ error here
        }
    }

    public class ScopeEntity
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserEntity> Users { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ScopeKey { get; set; }
        public virtual ScopeEntity Scope { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Scope { get; set; }
    }

}
```

The exception message says this

> "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. Mapping
> types:String -> ScopeEntitySystem.String -> ConsoleApp.ScopeEntity"

I believe that AutoMapper is trying to map User.Scope to UserEntity.Scope rather than UserEntity.ScopeKey even though it is defined in the mapper configuration. I don't understand why it would do this if I have specifically told it how to map User.Scope.

The only thing that works is if I add the a specific mapping between UserModel and UserEntity to ignore the UserEntity.Scope like this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<UserModel, UserEntity>()
       .ForMember(s => s.Scope, opts => opts.Ignore());
```

Is there a better/cleaner was to accomplish this?

Comment: You need the `Ignore`. You seem to be confused by `ReverseMap`. Drop that and create the maps explicitly. If that's clearer, just use that. The problem starts with naming :)

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu
Two things confuse me here. 
1). I thought that ReverseMap reversed the mapping configuration so a mapping between fields one way would be the same the other. 
2). The mapping I am trying to do (User -> UserEntity) is the one I have defined (Scope->ScopeKey), so why is it complaining about the types in the other direction?

Comment: Additionally.. why doesn't config.AssertConfigurationIsValid() throw an exception if I add this after my configuration setup?

Answer (score -1):

Automapper uses the property name to pass field values to one type to other as default behaviour.
You have the property `Scope` with two different types.

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<UserModel, UserEntity>()
       .ForMember(s => s.Scope, opts => opts.Ignore());
```

With the above code is the way you have to configure the `UserEntity` to `UserModel` mapping but you are ignoring the `Scope` property of user Entity.

You could follow the [official doc](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html) and configure the reverse mapping  like this:

```
 cfg.CreateMap<UserEntity, UserModel>()
                    .ForMember(s => s.Scope, opts => opts.MapFrom(dest => dest.ScopeKey))
                    .ReverseMap()
                    .ForPath(s => s.ScopeKey, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Scope));
```

With this, you keep the `Scope` property in each mapping, or you could use the `Scope.Key` sub-property in the mapping as documentation explain.

Comment: `ReverseMap` already reverses `MapFrom`s.

Comment: Yes, but `Scope`  properties are different types, and ignore is not the greatest solution. Is better configure the entire conversion. Regards

Comment: That's not relevant. You code doesn't do anything. Remove the last line and you'll see. Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: That´s the documentation code, I just change the variable names. 

**If you need to customize this, for a reverse map you can use ForPath:**

Read the [docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html) please:

**For most cases you shouldn’t need this, as the original MapFrom will be reversed for you. Use ForPath when the path to get and set the values are different.**
In this case, the paths are different.

Comment: Yes, I missing your point. I just see the exception that said `String` can't be mapped to `ScopeEntity`, and docs said if you use `MapFroms`, then AutoMapper will attempt to reverse the map but in this case that's not happens, then using `ForPath` is the convenient way to do this reverse configuration.